# Convert Jackery (solar generator) to use as UPS without losing battery quality

Tags: ups

I have bought [this](https://www.jackery.com/products/explorer-240-portable-power-station) Jackery device and I want to use it as UPS. I know that if I would connect it in between of socket and load it will act as UPS, but that will degrade the battery quickly. My question is there something I can put in between, so it will use jackery only if power from socket is off?

Comment: What is smth? Did you mean SMPS (switch mode power supply)?

Comment: smth == "something"?

Comment: smth == "something"